# Javascript (jQuery): next() gives me "li.next()" instead of "li"

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Confusing title, huh? I tried to explain it as best as i could.

What i mean is, if i have a menu like this:

```
<ul>
    <li> Home </li>
    <li class="current"> Portfolio </li>
    <li> Store </li>
    <li> About </li>
</ul>
```

and use the .next() method to get the next element FROM the current one:

```
$('ul li.current').next()
```

the result selector is:

```
ul li.current.next()
```

instead of a real selector. I mean, i can't target `ul li.current.next()` with CSS (and therefore it isn't a "real" selector). The real selector would look like `ul li`.

Is there any way to get the "real" selector of the next element?

Comment: can you show more js than that?

Comment: What is the problem? Do you want to get an equivalent CSS selector?

Comment: If you do `var test = $('#ul li'); alert(test.html()); test = test.next(); alert(test.html());` does it work as expected? I'm thinking your selector is too narrow to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the equivalent CSS selector, it would be:

```
ul li.current + li
```

See: [Adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators)

**Note:** [Not supported in IE6](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t12).

Also note that jQuery does not use CSS selectors to match all the elements. The selector syntax is just similar (it is a superset) to CSS because it seemed to be the most natural way. It uses methods provided by the browser (e.g. [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll)) where it can but it also has to *traverse* the DOM in order to find the elements.

E.g. you can never match `$('td').closest('tr')` with CSS as you cannot "move up" with CSS.

I hope this answers your question, if not please clarify it.

Comment: thats cool didn't know you could do that still learning css though haha ie6 bahh

Comment: It turns out i didn't need to do it this way, but i still needed to know how to do it, and your solution worked. Thanks! (and i stopped supporting IE6 months ago, so no worries about that!)

Answer (score 0):

`$('ul li.current').next()` will simply return the next `<li>`. It will return

```
<li> Store </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $li = $("ul li.current").next();
  $li.css("font-weight", "bold");
});
```

Or you can skip the var assignment and access it like this:

```
$("ul li.current").next().css("text-decoration", "underline");
```